VBA to split data from 1 tab to multiple tabs based on the values from one column
I am not an expert in VBA so asking for help.
I have this file the excel file format and i would like to have the same data but into different tabs based on one CLIENT NAME(column I) per tab.
I hope this makes sense.
Thank you in advance.
the same data but to have one customer in different sheet tabs
